# Using iphone app to upload video content to a website

Tags: ios, iphone, video, upload

This might be obvious but I'm going to ask anyway!

Are there any restrictions by apple regarding using a phone app to record and upload video to a website?

Comment: This might be obvious but I'm going to ask anyway! -- (-1 for this

Comment: /shrugs, don't know for certain so I asked my for peers opinion :/

Answer (score 1):

no there is not.